# discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that privately welcomes a new user to a Discord server and sends a private message when a user leaves the server. I can get the welcome message working, but when I add the code after on_member_remove() there is an error:

> discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot send messages to this user

I use the latest version of discord and Python 3.6.

This is the code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('-----')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
    await member.send("Welcome!")
    print("Sent message to " + member.name)


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " has left")
    await member.send("Goodbye")
    print("Sent message to " + member.name)


client.run(mytoken)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only send messages to people if you share a server.  The `on_member_remove` event triggers after the member has left the server, so you can no longer message them.